# Python 2.7 Value Error: Need more than 0 vales to unpack (Learn Python the Hard Way Ex 41)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have read all the answers related to unpacking errors and LPTHW ex 41 plus re-checked my code for an hour and I still don't get my error.

The following is my code:

```
import random
from urllib import urlopen 
import sys

WORD_URL = "http://learncodethehardway.org/words.txt"
WORDS = []

PHRASES = {
"class ###(###):":
    "Make a class named ### that is-a ###.",
"class ###(object):\n\tdef __init__(self, ***)" :
    "class ### has-a __init that takes self and *** parameters.",
"class ###(object):\n\tdef ***(self, @@@)":
    "class ### has-a function named *** that takes self and @@@ parameters.",
"*** = ###()":
    "Set *** to an instance of class ###.",
"***.***(@@@)": 
    "From *** get the *** function, and call it with parameters self, @@@.",
"***.*** = '***'":
    "From *** get the *** attribute and set it to '***'."
}

# do they want to drill phrases first
PHRASE_FIRST = False
if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == "english":
    PHRASE_FIRST = True

# load up the words from the website
for word in urlopen(WORD_URL).readlines():
    WORDS.append(word.strip())

def convert(snippet, phrase):
    class_names = [w.capitalize() for w in
                random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("###"))]
    other_names = random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("***"))
    results = []
    param_names = []

    for i in range(0, snippet.count("@@@")): 
        param_count = random.randint(1,3)
        param_names.append(', '.join(random.sample(WORDS, param_count)))

    for sentence in snippet, phrase:
        result = sentence[:]

    # fake class names
    for word in class_names:
        result = result.replace("###", word, 1)

    # fake other names
    for word in other_names:
        result = result.replace("***", word, 1)

    # fake parameter lists
    for word in param_names:
        result = result.replace("@@@", word, 1)

        results.append(result)

    return results

# keep going until they hit CTRL-D
try:
    while True:
        snippets = PHRASES.keys()
        random.shuffle(snippets)

        for snippet in snippets:
            phrase = PHRASES[snippet]
            question, answer = convert(snippet, phrase)
            if PHRASE_FIRST:
                question, answer = answer, question

            print question

            raw_input(">")
            print "ANSWER: %s\n\n" % answer #ERROR : after print - weird

except EOFError:
    print "\nBye"
```

The exact error is:

```
Value Error: Need more than 0 vales to unpack
```

I am just starting, so an explanation of why the error occurred and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the *full* traceback?

Comment: The *exact* error isn't the *complete* error!

Comment: You also added a space into the exception name; it's normally `ValueError`. Did you type the exception in by hand? Please use copy and paste instead.

Comment: At a guess, I'd say that `convert()` returned an empty list (`result` is empty).

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct except the indentation of your last 3 for loops, which should be nested.

Indent the following by 4 spaces and you should be good to go:

```
# fake class names
for word in class_names:
    result = result.replace("###", word, 1)

# fake other names
for word in other_names:
    result = result.replace("***", word, 1)

# fake parameter lists
for word in param_names:
    result = result.replace("@@@", word, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an indentation problem in your code, the 3 `for` loops must be  nested in the first one

```
for sentence in snippet, phrase:
    result = sentence[:]

    # fake class names
    for word in class_names:
        result = result.replace("%%%", word, 1)


    # fake other names
    for word in other_names:
       result = result.replace("***", word, 1)


    # fake parameter lists
    for word in param_names:
       result = result.replace("@@@", word, 1)


    results.append(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `convert` function, you modify `result` several times, without appending to the `results` list. You did it correctly on the last loop, but you probably need to add it to all the others:

```
for sentence in snippet, phrase:
    result = sentence[:]
    results.append(result)                  # added this

# fake class names
for word in class_names:
    result = result.replace("###", word, 1)
    results.append(result)                  # added this

# fake other names
for word in other_names:
    result = result.replace("***", word, 1)
    results.append(result)                  # added this

# fake parameter lists
for word in param_names:
    result = result.replace("@@@", word, 1)
    results.append(result)  # this one was already here
```

Otherwise, `results` remains an empty list, and `convert` returns `[]`. That can't be unpacked properly here:

```
question, answer = convert(snippet, phrase)
```

Because you've required exactly two elements: the question, and the answer.